# Decrypting my router config backup file

Tags: encryption, router

so I have this ONT router/mode (ZTE F660) provided to me by the ISP, it's interface contains very little settings and I wanted to see if I can get anything useful from it's config backup file. The file generated has a '.cfg' extension and it is encrypted. Is there anyway for me to decrypt it? I tried RouterPassView but I the file wasn't even detected. Is there anything else I can try?